# Database deployment in Azure DevOps

Tags: mysql, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, dbup

We are using DbUp migration task (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johanclasson.UpdateDatabaseWithDbUp) for deploying the SQL scripts to Microsoft SQL server in Azure DevOps and this works perfectly fine when I need to deploy to a single database but could someone please help me how can I use this task for multiple databases in the same server or any other methods we can use for multiple databases.

[image: DbUp migration]

Comment: Do you have a limited number of databases? Can you add separate DbUp task for each of them -- and have the scripts in different directories?

Comment: No we have more than 20 databases and it keeps expanding

Answer (score 0):

It all depends how you have your scripts organized. However, assuming that you have scripts separated by database - each database has it's own folder than what yout need is just provider proper value for `Script Folder Path` and proper connection string with database. In this case it will endup in having one task per database.

Comment: For the dbUp.database variable we can add only one database in the release pipelines which will be used by all the tasks added in the pipeline

Comment: You need variable per database, or split database across many stages than you can have the same variable with different value for each stage.

Comment: we cannot have multiple values for dbup.database variable which is associated with the dbup migration task, please find the screenshot attached in the question